# Coinbase API for application

Tags: coinbase-api

I am planning to integrate Coinbase API in an application. Can I get a developer account created in Coinbase for testing. I do not want to use my own Coinbase account that has gone through KYC.

Can someone point me to developer Coinbase registration?

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase used to have a public API endpoints, but they are now requiring authentication for most of their endpoints (including websockets).

You could use a third party API that offers a connection to Coinbase. Cryptowatch and Shrimpy are two examples of API's that would allow you to do that (there are many more).

However, your IP address along with the information you use to sign up for these third party API's will be tracked for KYC as well. This should not matter to you unless you intend on doing something malicious.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with node then it has library even for python you can simply install libraries and send requests through your api key and api secret.

```
npm install coinbase

pip install coinbase
```

but these libraries are deprecated while ago but still in use

refer for coinbase docs for more info
https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-key-authentication